# Total Gravitational Potential between two objects?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

It's taken me a while to formulate what i've been thinking about, but what is the *total* gravitational energy between two objects, not the instantaneous force between them?

For example: imagine two bowling balls in a hypothetical universe where they are the only objects in the universe, but all the other physical laws are the same.

In scenario one, they're at rest next to each other. In scenario two, they're a million light years apart.

If you "let them go" in Scenario 1, since they are at rest, as their masses can't overcome the electrical forces between the atoms they're made of, nothing happens.

In scenario two, they'll slowly move together... it might take billions of years, but eventually they'll collide with enormous force.

What i want is the total energy with which these objects would collide in scenario 2 before letting them go.

I've tried running integrals from Newton's equation and they end up giving me crazy solutions (like $10^{24}$ joules at $0.2$ meters apart using Planck lengths as the lower bound) so i'm not arranging the equation correctly.

Comment: Please show us the integral you calculated in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

According to Google, the radius of a bowling ball is 8.595 inches, and its mass is about 5 kg.  Therefore, the minimum distance between the centers of masses should be set to $d = 2 * 8.595$ inches.  If we assume the potential energy is zero at infinity and $-Gm^2/d$ at contact, then the kinetic energy of the system, when the bowling balls collide, will be $T = \Delta U = Gm^2/d$, which is about $3.82139*10^{-9}$ Joules, or $1.9107*10^{-9}$ Joules per bowling ball, which implies a velocity of 0.0000276456 m/s at impact.